# Prestashop Login First

Tags: authentication, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I use latest `prestashop 1.6.1.4`, I want to every customer firstly login on site and then they have access all over pages of website, without login user can't do anything on site.

So, I want know that there is any configuration at `backoffice` side and if **Yes** then how can do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built in function to do this, but you can easily override the FrontController to achieve this behavior.

Put this code inside `/override/classes/controller/FrontController.php`:

```php
<?php

class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        if (!$this->context->customer->isLogged() && $this->php_self != 'authentication' && $this->php_self != 'password')
        {
            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=authentication?back=index');
        }
    }
}
```

If the user is not on an authentication page or a forgot password page he will be redirected to the authentication page. After log in he will be redirected to the home.

---

**EDIT:**

If the file `FrontController.php` doesn't exist, you will have to create it and delete the file `/cache/class_index.php`. `class_index` caches every classes path on your website. So if you create a new Class File, you need to delete it to let Prestashop search for newly created ones.

Comment: `FrontController.php` file not exist on given path

Comment: @GuRu did you try my solution? If you need any more help feel free to ask

Comment: Sorry i didn't because of right now i am on job, after leave from job i try it. I also reads all your other answer related prestashop, impressed on and +1 to every.

Comment: @GuRu You're welcome, if you have any other questions feel free to ask. Have a good day.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such configuration for this in back office. You can only achieve this by developing a custom module for your store, that uses a hook that is called on all the pages (hookDisplayHeader or hookDisplayTop etc.)

If you don't want to create a module for this then you can also achieve the same by overriding FrontController.php as it is called on each and every page of PrestaShop.

Comment: NEVER touch the core files. This is what overrides are for.

Comment: there is no such thing, if you are comfortable enough then you can edit one

Comment: Erm... you shouldn't advice that to people, it has nothing to do with being comfortable. Whatever you add to the core will be gone when you update the shop. And there `is` such thing as overrides, which is why @Florian Lemaitre's answer received more up votes, because his solution is way better. Your should edit your answer and remove the advice to modify the core files, seriously.

Comment: Thanks @Raghubendra Singh +1. But, I want to know that what actual `FrontController.php` have do and where is it use?

Comment: when any page of PrestaShop is called in front end then the init() function of FrontController.php (located at /classes/controller/FrontController.php) is called, you can simply override this function to achieve what you want

Comment: Ok, good. Your given Path and also `Florian Lemaitre` given path are different. So, which one is right.

Comment: the path given by me has the core FrontController.php file and at the path given by him you have to create a new file so that the core file can be overriden

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109151/discussion-between-guru-and-raghubendra-singh).